# Tabular(x) cell filled with text from a macro

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to generate a table containing some static text and some text that should be supplied from a defined macro. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc, graphicx, booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe,width=0.85\paperwidth]{geometry}

\newcommand{\lsubject}{Naturfag}
\newcommand{\ldate}{20.08.13}
\newcommand{\lclass}{9D}
\newcommand{\lduration}{90 min.}
\newcommand{\lstart}{0815}
\newcommand{\lend}{0945}
\newcommand{\lcompetence}{Gjøre greie for hvilke biotiske og abiotiske faktorer som inngår i et økosystem og forklare sammenhengen mellom faktorene.}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{*{4}{X}}
    \toprule
    Dato: \ldate & Klasse: \lclass & Varighet: \lduration & Tidspunkt: \lstart--\lend \\
    Fag: \lsubject & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Kompetansemål (K06): \lcompetence} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

With the flattering output of

[image]

The intention is that the text in `\lcompetence` should fill 3/4 of the page (such that the columns in the first row is evenly distributed across the text width, thus the `multicolumn` environment in row 2), but it doesn't linebreak properly. It rather squeezes the other columns together. I've tried to wrap the `\lcompetence` in a `parbox`, but that resulted in the lower left cell `Fag: Naturfag` (it's not English :p) being centered with respect to height in the cell rather than in the top of it.

I've tried some solutions with both the `tabular` and the `tabularx` environment, thus the question title.

Is there an elegant way of fixing this so the `\lcompetence` content fills 3/4 of the text width nicely? It feels like this question could have been answered before, but I'm not able to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to teach `tabularx` to use the correct horizontal size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc, graphicx, booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe,width=0.85\paperwidth]{geometry}

\newcommand{\lsubject}{Naturfag}
\newcommand{\ldate}{20.08.13}
\newcommand{\lclass}{9D}
\newcommand{\lduration}{90 min.}
\newcommand{\lstart}{0815}
\newcommand{\lend}{0945}

\newcommand{\lcompetence}{Gjøre greie for hvilke biotiske og abiotiske faktorer som inngår 
i et økosystem og forklare sammenhengen mellom faktorene.}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{*{4}{X}}
\toprule
Dato: \ldate & Klasse: \lclass & Varighet: \lduration & Tidspunkt: \lstart--\lend \\
Fag: \lsubject & 
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep\relax}X}
    {Kompetansemål (K06): \lcompetence} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But there's no need to use `tabularx` for this application:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc, graphicx, booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe,width=0.85\paperwidth]{geometry}

\newcommand{\lsubject}{Naturfag}
\newcommand{\ldate}{20.08.13}
\newcommand{\lclass}{9D}
\newcommand{\lduration}{90 min.}
\newcommand{\lstart}{0815}
\newcommand{\lend}{0945}

\newcommand{\lcompetence}{Gjøre greie for hvilke biotiske og abiotiske faktorer som inngår 
i et økosystem og forklare sammenhengen mellom faktorene.}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\toprule
Dato: \ldate & Klasse: \lclass & Varighet: \lduration & Tidspunkt: \lstart--\lend \\
Fag: \lsubject & 
  \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr .75\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
    {Kompetansemål (K06): \lcompetence} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for saying not to use my package (although I really ought to make multicolumn easier in TX....)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for both explaining what I didn't understand at all with the `multicolumn` column width, and supplying a smarter solution. Takktakk =)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\multicolumn{3}{p{.75\linewidth}}{Kompetansemål (K06): \lcompetence}` (since you're using exactly 4 `X`-columns). The `l`eft-alignment doesn't allow for line-breaking.